# JavaScript concepts applying to JSX posts

Tags: discussion, tags, editing, specific-language

Many posts are tagged with [jsx](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jsx) as well as [javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and sometimes [ecmascript-6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6), but then those latter tags are often removed by others.

While I understand that [jsx](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jsx) is not syntactically valid [javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript), isn't it the case that many of the same concepts of the latter apply to the former? As such, does [javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) not apply?

For instance, if a question with [jsx](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jsx) has a bunch of code where variables are declared with `let`, an answer might include advice to use `const` wherever it makes sense. But if somebody looking to answer such a question sees that [javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) was removed from the question then that person might be apt to skip the question because they want to work towards badge progress on that tag.

Perhaps this is akin to [c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) where [c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) doesn’t apply- if so, just say so.

Comment: Are you suggesting something in particular should be done? I am not sure I understand what this post is suggesting, or asking....

Comment: If you want to add all tags that even remotely apply to a question, most questions would get more than the 5 tags allowed and tags would lose their value. While I see what you're getting at, I'm fairly sure we should leave it as-is.

Comment: JSX should always be tagged if used in the code. There's a huge difference between, for example, React code with and without JSX. How I see it is if the question can still be accurately described without a certain tag, remove that tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire JavaScript ecosystem is a mess, because you have languages built on-top of other languages, with subsets of those languages it's a mess.

As we know JavaScript is a language, but it is also a subset of the ECMAScript language specification. ECMAScript also has other compliant languages, such as ActionScript and JScript. ECMAScript also has a couple of different versions, at the time of writing, 1, 2, 3, 3.1, 5, 6 (2015), 7 (2016), 8 (2017), 9 (2018) and next (Beta).

And so it's valid to say you have ES2 compatible ActionScript. Assuming it exists. Just like you can say you have ES9 JavaScript.

But it doesn't stop there, JSX and TypeScript build on-top of JavaScript *and* ES6. But they also add more to the language. But JSX can work with TypeScript, and so following your suggestion we should tag all JSX TypeScript questions with, [ecmascript-6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6)[javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)[typescript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typescript)[jsx](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jsx), leaving *one* tag for any information that isn't about the language. And with so many libraries in JavaScript you need those tags!

You also have languages like CoffeeScript that transpile to JavaScript, but don't extend it or ECMAScript. And "isn't it the case that many of the same concepts of the latter apply to the former?" So this should include the JavaScript language tag too? Should we include ECMAScript too?

---

As we can only have 5 tags, we have to be a little bit sparing in how we use them. I suggest following the Python tags. All Python questions are tagged with [python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python), if it works in one version then you include [python-3.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) or [python-2.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x). Things like IronPython and Jython are different versions of Python and so would be the sole language tag. But can also include the version tag. [jython](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jython)[python-2.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) is ok.

But if the question includes all the language tags, and any other tags that would make sense then I see no harm in having the following tags [javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)[ecmascript-6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6)[typescript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typescript)[jsx](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jsx)[angular](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular). If the person is doing a programming challenge then it's more than ok to change the tags to [javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)[typescript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typescript)[jsx](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jsx)[angular](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/angular)[programming-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-challenge). But if you just remove the tags for the sake of it, then I don't see it as an improvement. As the tags *aren't wrong*, and it just reduces the discoverability of the question.